# How does route config system in codeigniter work?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I learn and follow some codeigniter series in youtube like in channel 'Traversy Media'. in his video when he makes a users controller to manage register and login system, he didn't set any routes in config  for users controller. Why does it can run normally when call `localhost/ciblog/users/register` ?

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['posts/create'] = 'posts/create';
$route['posts/update'] = 'posts/update';
$route['posts/(:any)']='posts/view/$1';
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)']='pages/view/$1'; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
?>
```

so if in the routes.php there are line `$route['(:any)']='pages/view/$1';`, so it will be `localhost/pages/view/users/register`. And it should be error. Can someone explain because I'm new in codeigniter ?

Comment: code + typo + grammar

Comment: *And it should be error*... why should it be error? please explain